# Chrome is blocking Flash player, how to play RTMP stream?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I have RTMP stream which I played using Flash player fallback in the video.js library. A few weeks ago I have been noticed that these players stopped working. I tried to update video.js to the new version, but I still getting error notification "No compatible source was found for this media.".

I would like to ask that is possible to run RTMP stream after permanently ban NPAPI for Chrome browser?

Related Links:
http://www.miracletutorials.com/flash-support-in-google-chrome-under-fire/

Many thanks forany advice

Comment: It depends on the used codecs. If it's `H.264`/`AAC` you can just remux it to HLS. For example there's an RTMP module for Nginx that allows you to do this.

Comment: Chrome expects a `.swf` file (Flash app) to be embedded within HTML code of your page. No swf embed == no Flash displayed. Simple as that. VideoJS (by design) may not be best option for this new rule of Chrome...